# jQuery's getScript function, wait for the retrieved variable

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery getScript function:

```
jQuery.getScript(script,function() {
    src = an_ajax_request;
});
```

The problem is, I need this variable outside the function, to make a string:

```
if(src == "") string = "string"+src;
//I always get an empty src value here!
```

But if the getScript function takes longer to load (loading async), I get the src value in the console, but the src is still empty when I try to  build the string.

**Question: how can I make the string generation wait for the src value to get retrieved by the getScript function?**

Comment: run the function in the callback of `getSCript`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax request, do something like this.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "getSrc",
  success: function(src){
   string = "string"+src;
  }
});
```